# Pyttsx3 is not installing on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

I have python 3.7.6 installed and when I try to install pyttsx3 on my windows 10, I had an error, that I need mac os, but it installing on another computer with windows. I have tried to reinstall python and cleared pip cache, but it didn't work.
This is an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\pfkcs\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\pfkcs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y_mkf7t4\pyobjc-core\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\pfkcs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y_mkf7t4\pyobjc-core\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\pfkcs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y_mkf7t4\pyobjc-core\
Complete output (2 lines):
running egg_info
error: PyObjC requires macOS to build
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/381) post titled "pyautogui fails to install on windows- error: PyObjC requires macOS to build"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While installing pyttsx3: Command errored out with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909818/while-installing-pyttsx3-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install -U pyttsx3`

If still not working, you may have to install a specific version of pyttsx3. The most stable previous version is 2.71, you can install it by `pip install -U pyttsx3==2.71`

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to run your Python code in an virtual env, by either anaconda if you have it installed: `conda create -n <venv name> python=3.6` or `python -m venv .` if you do not have anaconda. Then either `pip install pyttsx3` or `py -m pip install pyttsx3` if the other doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

First you have to install Python for windows extension. [click here to download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) 
Then you’ll need to give your virtualenv access to the system site-packages in order to install pyttsx.:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages myproj
. myproj/bin/activate
pip install pyttsx
```

may be this could help you

Comment: Just my two cents. I think it's better to use the "official" cpython windows distribution from www.python.org ... which exists also in 64 bits.