# While installing pyttsx3: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip, pyttsx

```
$ pip install pyttsx3
Collecting pyttsx3
  Using cached pyttsx3-2.80-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pyobjc>=2.4
  Using cached pyobjc-6.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
Collecting comtypes; "win32" in sys_platform
  Using cached comtypes-1.1.7.zip (180 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==6.1
  Using cached pyobjc-framework-SyncServices-6.1.tar.gz (42 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\abrar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Abrar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e8rlz1t4\\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Abrar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e8rlz1t4\\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Abrar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e8rlz1t4\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\pip-egg-info'
         l = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
      File "c:\users\abrar\appdata\local\programs\python\python3
```

i m trying this on python 3.7.3 and using latest pip version but i couldn't understand how to fix it

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug in `pyttsx3` 2.80: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/82. No fix yet. Try downgrading to `pyttsx3` 2.71:

```
pip install -U pyttsx3==2.71
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following command

```
pip install git+git://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3.git
```

It worked for me

I got the above command from pyttsx3 github [issues](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/86)

Answer (score 0):

First try installing wheel
`pip install wheel`
Then you can install pyttsx3, `pip install pyttsx3`, this should work for you.