# pyttsx3 not installing on windows(filenotFounderror)

Tags: python, file-not-found

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'c:\users\kvvinod\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
>   -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   egg_info --egg-base
>   'C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\pip-egg-info'
>            cwd: C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\
>       Complete output (15 lines):
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\setup.py",
>   line 20, in 
>           Extension(
>         File "C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\pyobjc_setup.py",
>   line 408, in Extension
>           os_level = get_os_level()
>         File "C:\Users\kvvinod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7kf48pty\pyobjc-framework-Security\pyobjc_setup.py",
>   line 218, in get_os_level
>           pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
>         File "c:\users\kvvinod\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\plistlib.py",
>   line 99, in readPlist
>           with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
>         File "c:\users\kvvinod\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py",
>   line 113, in **enter**
>           return next(self.gen)
>         File "c:\users\kvvinod\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\plistlib.py",
>   line 82, in _maybe_open
>           with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
>       ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909818/while-installing-pyttsx3-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1).

Comment: that is not working

Comment: showing error:No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32; "win32" in sys_platform->py
ttsx3==2.71)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `pyttsx3` 2.80: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/82. Not fix yet. Try downgrading to pyttsx3 2.71:

`pip install -U pyttsx3==2.71`