# I'm unable to install the pyttsx3 package

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyttsx

I tried various methods to solve this error. even downloaded the `.whl` file and then tried to run the command but every time it's the same error 
Any help from anyone would be really helpful
Have a Look !!

[image: cmd error while using the pip command]

Comment: Looks like your `pip` thinks you're running macOS. Maybe `pyobjc` doesn't support Windows?

Comment: @ForceBru `pyobjc` is indeed MacOS-specific, the problem here is that `pyttsx3` specifies the dependencies wrong, so the wheel pulls `pyobjc-security` on every platform.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59909885/7976758

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ Text, please! Images aren't helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search.

Answer (score 1):

The published wheel is broken and will be only installable on MacOS. Install from Git repository instead until the issue is fixed:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3@v2.84
```

Comment: So should I paste this in the terminal..!?

Comment: Yes. You should have Git installed in order for the command to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Buddy..It was really helpful

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider accepting the answer to resolve the question, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)