# unable to install pyttsx3 (text to speak module )

Tags: python, pip, pyttsx

I am unable to install pyttsx3 package using pip.
I tried  `pip install pyttsx3` but was unable to install it.

```
C:\Users\yashr\Desktop\SOFTWARES\brother> pip install pyttsx3
Collecting pyttsx3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/20/f6c582c5f2735ca5c55ae52f1ddbc7447fb3565b5ac2fdc24a8d534f4aa1/pyttsx3-2.84-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyobjc>=2.4 (from pyttsx3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/c9/83b256bb7f771a9e4232518005d6f237ae79215283cf5ea234141751b36a/pyobjc-6.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting comtypes; "win32" in sys_platform (from pyttsx3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/b8/f8aa21774acb4535e32f6a89055876ca497ff806f9b1b1912b469284a61e/comtypes-1.1.7.zip
Collecting pyobjc-framework-WebKit==6.1 (from pyobjc>=2.4->pyttsx3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/64/353b9512c0dddb0159a17a231a9e3bdb594d7d891ffd74d0b26ee629d7b3/pyobjc-framework-WebKit-6.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\yashr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxvtccap\pyobjc-framework-WebKit\setup.py", line 27, in <module>       
        for fn in os.listdir("Modules")
      File "C:\Users\yashr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxvtccap\pyobjc-framework-WebKit\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\yashr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxvtccap\pyobjc-framework-WebKit\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
      File "c:\users\yashr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\plistlib.py", line 99, in readPlist
        with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
      File "c:\users\yashr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "c:\users\yashr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\plistlib.py", line 82, in _maybe_open
        with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\yashr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxvtccap\pyobjc-framework-WebKit\
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I would appreciate some help regarding the installation of pyttsx3 package.

Comment: Did you already try to upgrade pip, as recommended?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While installing pyttsx3: Command errored out with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909818/while-installing-pyttsx3-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3.git
```

From [here](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/86).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac then try pip3 install pyttsx3 . If you are on windows then try pasting this into the terminal - pip install git+git://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3.git

If that doesn't work - then check the PyPa Documentation and they will explain in a much better way .

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command.

```
conda install -c auto pyttsx
```